# Pandas `wide_to_long` extremely slow

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a dataframe from wide to long format, using the [`wide_to_long`](https://gist.github.com/jseabold/6653108) convenience function. While it generally does what it says on the tin, it quickly gets extremely slow.

The dataframe I have has a little over a thousand rows, with observations over 25 years (i.e. each variable is recorded in 25 columns, `col_1980`, `col_1981`, etc.). Doing the `wide_to_long` conversion takes about 7 minutes (!) when using 8 of my variables, plus there's LOTS of memory allocation (peaking at over 7GB, while the original data frame is less than 30MB).

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong? I know this is a fairly unspecific question, but I'm hoping someone might be able to give a hint anyway. Thanks!

--- EDITED TO ADD ---

As has rightly been pointed out, the question as posted above was generally unanswerable. I believe I might have found the problem now though, so maybe someone can help with this:

Consider a slightly amended version of the example dataframe in the docstring of `wide_to_long`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"age70" : {0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c"},
                   "age71" : {0 : "d", 1 : "e", 2 : "f"},
                   "agedum70" : {0 : 2.5, 1 : 1.2, 2 : .7},
                   "agedum71" : {0 : 3.2, 1 : 1.3, 2 : .1},
                   "X"     : dict(zip(range(3), np.random.randn(3)))
                   })
df["id"] = df.index
```

As you can see, the unique feature about this dataframe is that we have two variables starting with the same couple of characters (here I'm trying to represent the common occurence of having a variable and its dummy equivalent). When I now run: `pd.wide_to_long(df, ["age", "agehd"], i="id", j="year")`, `wide_to_long` will produce four `j` variables `[70,71,dum70,dum71]`. In my use case with 25 years and much more of these name clashes, this blew up the dataframe to many times its original size, explaining the slow performance and high memory allocation

I'm not sure whether I still have a question here - maybe if there's a way out of this apart from renaming all columns in my dataset so as to avoid this misidentification of variables?

Comment: I'd profile that code but it's doing a lot of melt and merge operations, can you post your starting and desired df result, you can probably achieve this using a combination of multi-indexing/pivoting/stacking

Comment: "fairly unspecific"?  Uh, yeah!  Need sample data and code.  I dunno much about `wide_to_long` but there are many other ways to do this type of thing in pandas that shouldn't take very long on such a small data set.

Comment: Thanks for your attempts at help with my - admittedly - very poor question. I've (potentially) worked out what went wrong and will amend the question accordingly to zero in on the problem.